# Index exceeds matrix dimensions(matlab)

Tags: matlab

I wrote this code:

```
omiga= 7.543703405690999e+20;
semu= -2.045998237293904e+18;
delta_0= 2.000000000000000e-08;
x=0:10-10:10-3;
YY=(delta_0/(4*(1-omiga/semu)^2))*1/CC*exp(-x*(semu-omiga)^0.5)*(CC*exp(x(semu-omiga)^0.5)+1-omiga/semu)^2;
plot(x,YY);
```

And got the error

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
>
> Error in Untitled (line 5)
>       YY=(delta_0/(4*(1-omiga/semu)^2))*1/CC*exp(-x*(semu-omiga)^0.5)*(CC*exp(x(semu-omiga)^0.5)+1-omiga/semu)^2;

Why am I receiving this error?

Comment: Can you take the semicolon off of that `x=0:10-10:10-3;` line and run it again, and see what x is (and specifically, how *long* it is)?  I don't have a copy of MATLAB at the moment, but that line looks *really* weird...

Comment: this error appear !
Untitled

x =

   Empty matrix: 1-by-0

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in Untitled (line 5)
YY=(delta_0/(4*(1-omiga/semu)^2))*1/CC*exp(-x*(semu-omiga)^0.5)*(CC*exp(x(semu-omiga)^0.5)+1-omiga/semu)^2;

Comment: But before that error, IF YOU REMOVE THE SEMICOLON FROM THE END OF THE x = ... line and rerun ALL of that code, you should see and x = , and then another line, showing the value of x.  Because that REALLY should be appearing if you leave that semicolon off.  If it doesn't something is very very wrong.

Comment: x = Empty matrix 
 you mean this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you were trying to assign to `x`, but it comes out as an empty matrix. You then try to access the index `semu-omiga` of the `x` matrix, which is empty. Maybe spend some time with a Matlab tutorial.

Comment: Thanks! That what I was working towards with my questions above, but like I said, I don't have a MATLAB on this machine, so I was just trying to walking the user through the debugging steps :-)

Comment: Even after you fix your `x` matrix, you're going to get the same error because `semu-omiga` is a negative number. You can't access a negative index of a matrix.

Comment: so i just need to plot the func YY ?? any way to do that ? please  help me

Comment: The code you have written for YY is not valid. Seriously, go read a tutorial on Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Previous posts have correctly pointed out some of the syntax errors.  One additional suggestion...try to get your formula working for just one value of x before trying to do a vectorized computation.  Typically, with several multiplied terms, you are going to want to use

```
".*"
```

to do element-wise multiplication, instead of

```
"*"
```

which attempts to do matrix multiplication.

e.g.

```
   YY=(delta_0/(4*(1-omiga/semu)^2)).*1/CC*exp(-x*(semu-omiga)^0.5).*(CC*exp(x*(semu-omiga)^0.5)+1-omiga/semu)^2;
```